# Croogo - CakePHP site on new VPS not loading js and css

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, croogo

I've recently purchased a VPS on inmotionhosting.com, and having difficulty deploying my **Croogo 2.3.2** when loading any js, css, img files under my custom theme **/View/Themed/Mosaic/webroot** and under my Croogo plugins **/Vendor/croogo/croogo/Croogo/webroot/**.

Of course, I've included the said resources using the proper CakePHP convention in my **/View/Themed/Mosaic/Layouts/default.ctp**:

```
    echo $this->Html->css(array(
        'bootstrap',
        'bootstrap-theme',
        '/croogo/css/reset',
        'font-awesome.min',
        '../slick/slick',
        '../slick/slick-theme',
        '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
        'slicknav.min',
        'styles'
    ));
    echo $this->Layout->js();
    echo $this->Html->script(array(
        '/croogo/js/html5',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.0.min',
        '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.slug',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.cookie',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.minified',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/superfish',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/supersubs',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.tipsy',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.elastic-1.6.1.js',
        '/croogo/js/jquery/thickbox-compressed',
        '/croogo/js/underscore-min',
        'bootstrap.min',
        '../slick/slick.min',
        'jquery.slicknav.min',
        'theme.js',
    ));

    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
```

Croogo 2.3.2 has itself and cakephp run as a Vendor:

> /Vendor/croogo
>
> /Vendor/cakephp

Therefore, I have two **.htaccess** files.

> One under /home/mosaic40/v2.mosaicmarble.com/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

> One under /home/mosaic40/v2.mosaicmarble.com/webroot/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

> mod_rewrite is installed and activated.

Last but not least, before anyone starts suggesting about my httpd config, here it is:

```
DocumentRoot /home/mosaic40/v2.mosaicmarble.com/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I can't seem to put my finger on it. in short, the plugins' and theme's resources (js/css/img) are not being loaded for some reason.

**UPDATE 1:**
It appears /webroot assets are not being loaded as well (example: http://v2.mosaicmarble.com/uploads/FG204-G.jpg).
The said link is http://v2.mosaicmarble.com/ (to see what's being rendered).

Croogo v2.3.2
CakePHP v2.9.3
Linux Server with NGINX installed
mod_rewrite active (click on any link, you'll see pretty urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evident solution in the end was to disable NGINX... which is weird, because I own several other servers like Media Temple's VPS with NGINX installed and all my websites run flawlessly.

So, yea... disabling NGINX did the job.

Thank you @cgTag for your prompt response, it does help others in the future who may face a similar issue.

Comment: Everything in your question shows that you're running Apache and not nginx, and neither have anything to do with CakePHP's routing. I think you must have had more than one issue that were overlapping.

Comment: The question originally didn’t mention Nginx, I agree I must’ve communicated that before updating. I did try to include as much info as possible. But still, I do appreciate your efforts. I find this scenario unique in its way, because I didn’t find on SO a possible solution of disabling NGINX. I honestly still don’t know why disabling it made it work. But it did. It’s now running flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching assets for plugins via the dispatcher. You have to use a plugin namespace as the URL.

```
echo $this->Html->script('Croogo.html5');
```

See the manual on linking to plugin assets:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#linking-to-assets-in-plugins

Comment: Although you're right that starting cakephp version 2.1+ (i'm using 2.9.3) it is advised to start using Plugin syntax, the one i've used also works. the generated HTML is being generated correctly, example: http://v2.mosaicmarble.com/croogo/js/jquery/jquery.slug.js or http://v2.mosaicmarble.com/theme/Mosaic/js/theme.js